# Pandas - sort and group DataFrame and export it to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas

I've got a Dataframe object that looks like this:

```
time                                count                 source
2017-05-13 21:48:40.388             5984.0                source1
2017-05-13 21:48:48.228             5987.0                source1
2017-05-13 21:48:49.072             5998.0                source1
2017-05-14 22:38:07.507            18560.0                source2
2017-05-14 22:38:11.066            18560.0                source2
2017-05-15 20:29:51.709            18572.0                source2
2017-05-15 20:29:54.855            18572.0                source2
2017-05-17 12:05:16.092             4131.0                source3
2017-05-17 12:05:20.675             4132.0                source3
2017-05-17 12:05:22.397             4138.0                source3
```

from there, I'd like to get to a JSON file that looks like that:

```
[
    { 
        "date": "2017-05-14", 
        "source1": 5980, 
        "source2": 18550, 
        "source3": 4102 
    }, 
    { 
        "date": "2017-05-28", 
        "source1": 5984, 
        "source2": 18560, 
        "source3": 4131 
    }, 
]
```

Pandas should be able to handle that I guess - but I can't get it working it seems (just started with Pandas).

Then, I assume I first need to `resample('W')` my Dataframe.
Next probably it needs to be grouped by the time?

I've got actually quite some code but it's more like stepping in the dark and things I find online doesn't really fit my data structure.

```
dfNew.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
dfNew.dropna(inplace=True)

# Set the datetime column as the index
dfNew.index = dfNew['time']    
dfNew.dropna(inplace=True)

#dfNew = dfNew.groupby('source').resample('W').mean()
dfNew.sort_values ( 'time',  inplace = True )
grouper = dfNew.groupby([pd.TimeGrouper('W'), 'source'])

print ( grouper.head() )
```

Where do I go wrong or how could I achieve what I want?

Comment: I can't see how you can get your desired output from your input example. The dates don't seem to match.

Comment: Isn't the resample function usuful for that? In total I've got almost 200.000 datapoints that I'd like to resample and match to the closest weekly interval ...